# Force creation of Couchbase Lite 2.6 database

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

Whenever I want to open my Couchbase lite database on an empty `data/com.my.app/files/databaseName.cblite2` folder i.e.:

```
DatabaseConfiguration config = new DatabaseConfiguration();
database = new Database(databaseName, config);
```

I get the following error:

```
CouchbaseLiteException{CouchbaseLite,21,'file/data is not in the requested format'}
```

How can I enforce that a new database is created instead? So in case loading succeeds I would like to get the old database and in case the data is corrupt (error 21) I would like to get a new Couchbase database.

**Background:**

In order to test some functionality of my App with instrumentation tests, I hava a test rule that moves the local Couchbase files `db.sqlite3`, `db.sqlite3-shm` and `db.sqlite3-wal` to some backup location (`@Before`) and restores the original database after the test (`@After`).

Unfortunatly, whenever the database is empty, I get the above exception with code 21, which according to [Couchbase Documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.0/couchbase-lite-net/html/T_Couchbase_Lite_CouchbaseLiteError.htm) means that the database exists but has the wrong format.

When I inspect the folder structure in Android Studio's 'Device File Explorer' I see that loading succeeds if the folder `data/com.my.app/files/databaseName.cblite2` either contains a `db.sqlite3` file or if it completely missing. However, if the folder is empty, the exception it thrown.

When I manually delete the folder by setting a breakpoint, the test works just fine.
Is there I way to enforce the creation of the database?

**Edit:**

As manually deleting the folder prevents the error, my workaround is to delete the `databaseName.cblite2` folder from the file system in case it is empty.   While this is not the most elegant solution I found it acceptable for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is behaving as designed.

Couchbase considers the presence of the SQLite-created database directory as evidence that the database exists.  Deleting the contents of the folder is not a reasonable thing to do.  To delete the database you should, as you note in your edit, delete the directory and its contents.

Better yet, use `db.delete()`